# which operating system does sony ericsson mobile phones use

Tags: mobile, operating-system

which operating system does sony ericsson mobile phones use

- all models please

Comment: You want a list of all the operating systems ever used for *all Sony Ericsson mobile phones ever made* ?

Comment: This question can be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea - Goto the developer section of their website

Comment: This is not an answer. Please make into a comment instead?